# "scope.sh" is lacking for ranger file manager

Tags: shell-script, fedora, configuration, file-manager, ranger

Ranger is a file manager using Miller columns to navigate between the tree.

It has an external script called *scope.sh* that previews files utilizing external applications such as the `.torrent` files with `transmission-show`.

I've installed all the dependencies, that is the external binaries for it to function, but the file manager, that's `ranger` doesn't preview those files.

I checked `~/.config/ranger/` contents, and it turns out the script (`scope.sh`) is absent there.

I am on Fedora 25 and I have installed ranger normally through `dnf install ranger -y`.

Please help me with providing `scope.sh` file.

As I think that's the reason why `ranger` doesn't preview those files.

Answer (score 7):

For anyone else having the same problem/question, you can run 
`ranger --copy-config=fileyouwant` where `fileyouwant = all (for all the config files), commands, rc, rifle, scope`. 
That command should copy the default configuration file(s) of your choice to `~/.config/ranger/` .
For more information look through the manpage (`man ranger`)

Answer (score 1):

I found the file, that is `scope.sh` inside the [archive](http://nongnu.org/ranger/ranger-stable.tar.gz), within `/ranger/data/` directory. Not it shows the syntax highlighting, `.tar` content, and `.torrent` information as well.

I mean I found and extracted it from the archive and copied it to `~/.config/ranger/` directory where it should've been located.

For some reason I fail to understand, it didn't come with `rpm` installation through `dnf` on Fedora. Which is strange. But I'm happy that I finally could solve the issue, and did it by myself :P

Answer (score 0):

On distros that use .deb do this to know where the file is if you, for some reason, don't want to use the solution pointed by @cyphex:

```bsh
apt-file list ranger | grep scope.sh
```

After that, just manually copy the file.

If you don't have apt-file install it with:

```bsh
sudo apt-get install apt-file
```

Answer (score 0):

For global installation and configuration, on debian based systems these files can also be found on `/etc/ranger` (which are linked to the `/usr/lib/python3/..` directories.